# Aggregating on an array field

Tags: sql, arrays, database

I have the following data:

```
movie (string)         genres (string[])
"titanic"              ["romance", "historical", "drama"]
"spider-man"           ["sci-fi", "action"]
"casablanca"           ["romance", "classic"]
```

Is there a "standard" way -- at least conceptually speaking -- to aggregate on an array field? For example, doing something like:

```
SELECT genres, count(*) GROUP BY genres ORDER BY count(*) DESC, genres
```

If seems to me the result should be something like:

```
genres         count
"romance"      2
"action"       1
"classic"      1
"drama"        1
"historical"   1
"sci-fi"       1
```

Is this how most database engines do aggregating on an array field? I'd be interested to see some examples of how aggregations would be done in that engine.

Usually when I've done it I get complains and have to manually make this conversion, for example in pandas:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'movie':['titanic', 'spider-man', 'casablanca'], 'genres': [['romance', 'historical', 'drama'], ['sci-fi', 'action'],['romance','classic']]})
df.groupby('genres').first() # will error, or converting to tuple will not unnest the array
```

Comment: If you are using SQL server 2017 , you can use string_agg and string split, if it is less than that you may have to use function to split the string (with XML nodes most likely)

Comment: @Avi -- thanks, do most or any databases support grouping on a list field? What is the "Default" operation if there is one?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and only very few databases support real arrays). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- actually, I'm not using a DBMS, I'm writing something and I'm looking to various DBs to compare how they're doing aggregations on a list field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is this how most db engines do aggregating on an array field?*

"Most DB engines" do not support arrays to begin with. To my knowledge only Postgres, H2 and HSQLDB fully support arrays.

In the SQL standard you would need to `unnest()` the array in order to achieve this (the following is Postgres syntax, but I think it's pretty close to the SQL standard):

```
SELECT ut.genre, count(*) 
FROM the_table
  cross join lateral unnest(genres) as ut(genre) 
GROUP BY ut.genre 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC, ut.genre
```

The three RDBMS I know that support arrays, would group by the "complete array", not the individual elements. And at least in Postgres, the order of the elements matters, `['romance', 'classic']` is a different array than `['classic', 'romance']`.

So `GROUP BY genres` would return three distinct rows.

I *think* this is also what the SQL standard defines, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is very clear. Out of curiosity, is there every a usage for doing a group by "complete array"? I can see the need for doing `unnest` as the default operation if one were to group by an array, but grouping on the full array seems like it'd have no use -- or have you seen over use cases for that?

Comment: You can add Google Bigquery, Hive, and most databases based on Postgres (which is a lot).  There may be others as well.